# Need help searching in a list in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, typed-racket

I have written the following functions for `find-index`:

```
(: finind : (Listof Integer) Integer -> (Option Integer))
;; helper function for find-index
(define (finind a b)
   (let loop ((a a) (c 0))
      (cond 
         ((empty? a) 'None)
         ((equal? (first a) b) (Some c))
         (else (loop (rest a) (add1 c))))))

(: find-index : (Integer -> Boolean) (Listof Integer) 
                 -> (Option (Pr (Option Integer) Integer)))
;; return the first item to pass the test, if there is one,
;; along with its (0-based) index
(define (find-index f x)
   (match x
      ('() 'None)
      ((cons hd '())
         (if (f hd) (Some (Pr (finind x hd) hd)) 'None)) 
      ((cons hd tl)
         (if (f hd) (Some (Pr (finind x hd) hd)) 
                    (find-index f tl)))))
```

Now, `finind` works perfectly on its own, but when I use it with `find-index`, it only gives back `(Some 0)`.

The result for `(finind (list 45 41 9) 9)` is `(Some 2)`.

But, the result for `(find-index (lambda ([t : Integer]) (< t 10)) (list 45 41 9))` is `(Some (Pr (Some 0) 9))`, even though it should be `(Some (Pr (Some 2) 9))`.

So i know that it maybe happening because i have `(finind x hd)` to display my index and because its `hd` it doesn't change. however how do i get around that? i have been trying but in vain. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: In the last cond term when predicate is false you are recursing to `find-index` and you don't pass on the index offset in any way so it cannot know that it's the third time you are doing it. Perhaps wrap with an index and use that instead will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: You're not passing `'(45 41 9)` to `finind`, you're passing the first tail whose head satisfies `f`, which is `'(9)`.

Comment: Can you please reflect the correct way to do it in the code? I know the problem but now how to change the code to make it work :(

Comment: @NishantAggarwal When you pass your test function `f` and `'(41 9)` the result would be `(find-index f (cdr '(41 9)))` which will find it but that instance of `find-index` has no idea that it is looking at the second index and not the first. It looks for me as you would like to pass the function as well to the helper and have `find-index` just do a call to `findind` or you can move the helper in `find-index` so you have access to `f`.

Comment: you need to call `(finind original-x hd)` instead of `(finind x hd)`, but after `(find-index f tl)` you've forgotten all about the original `x`, and use its tail as the list, afterwards. The minimal change would be to save `original-x` at the start of `find-index`, moving the looping into an internal definition, e.g. with a *named loop* construct. But also, the type is off, you don't need the nested `Option`, there's no chance an element of a list won't be there the second time we search for same element in the same list. Lastly, the 2nd case in your `match` expression is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since `hd` is the head of `x`, `(finind x hd)` will always be zero.

It's unclear what the `Pr` type is for, but from the comment it sounds like you want an optional pair.
You can get the index using an accumulator parameter:

```
(: find-index : (Integer -> Boolean) (Listof Integer) -> (Option (Pair Integer Integer)))
(define (find-index pred? ls)
  (: find-help : (Listof Integer) Integer -> (Option (Pair Integer Integer)))
  (define (find-help ls i)
    (cond [(null? ls) 'None]
          [(pred? (car ls)) (Some (cons i (car ls)))]
          [else (find-help (cdr ls) (+ i 1))]))
  (find-help ls 0))
```

(I made my own `Option` type; yours may be different.)
Test run:

```
> (find-index (lambda ([t : Integer]) (< t 10)) (list 45 41 9))
- : (U 'None (Some (Pairof Integer Integer)))
(Some '(2 . 9))
> (find-index (lambda ([t : Integer]) (< t 10)) (list 45 41 49))
- : (U 'None (Some (Pairof Integer Integer)))
'None
> (find-index (lambda ([t : Integer]) (< t 10)) (list 9 41 9))
- : (U 'None (Some (Pairof Integer Integer)))
(Some '(0 . 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [functional-lib](https://pkgn.racket-lang.org/package/functional-lib) package to make this easy for you

```
(require data/maybe)    

(define (find f xs)
  (cond ((empty? xs) nothing)
        ((f (car xs)) (just (car xs)))
        (else (find f (cdr xs)))))

(define (find-index f xs (i 0))
  (cond ((empty? xs) nothing)
        ((f (car xs)) (just i))
        (else (find-index f (cdr xs) (add1 i)))))

(find (λ (x) (< x 10)) '(10 11 3 2 1))       ;; (just 3)
(find-index (λ (x) (< x 10)) '(10 11 3 2 1)) ;; (just 2)

(find (λ (x) (< x 0)) '(10 11 3 2 1))       ;; nothing
(find-index (λ (x) (< x 0)) '(10 11 3 2 1)) ;; nothing
```

Comment: Should these functions perhaps be added to `functional-lib` somewhere?

Comment: @AlexisKing I'm flattered that you think so. I've never contributed to a racket package before, so I'm probably not the most effective person to get them added. Can you think of other ways to make the procedures better?

Comment: In some sense, it would make the most sense for them to be in `collections-lib`, but unfortunately that library predates `functional-lib`, and it doesn’t use `data/maybe` in its API. I wonder if it would be possible to add an alternative API somewhat gracefully.

Comment: @AlexisKing is it common for `typed/racket` users to use plain-old `racket` packages? Is there a nice way to increase interoperability?

Comment: Ah, I think it depends on the package. The `require/typed` form makes it reasonably easy to use simple untyped packages in TR, but TR can’t handle `functional-lib` or `collections-lib` because they use `racket/generic`, and TR does not (currently) support generics. The easiest way to make things interop well is to just write them in Typed Racket, since you can pretty much always use TR code from untyped code but not vice versa. Of course, I really like some of the Racket features that TR doesn’t support (like generics), so a lot of my packages are incompatible with TR.

Comment: @AlexisKing thanks for the insight — I know next to nothing about the topic ^_^